# Styling doesn't align a button with a <div> block

Tags: html, css

Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kRU6r/1/).

This is suppose to give this :

[image: Correct styling]

But it does that instead :

[image: Wrong styling]

Here is the HTML for that part of the page :

```
<input type="submit" name="BT_resetZoom" value="Reset coordinates" id="BT_resetZoom" tabindex="10" style="height:50px;width:125px;">
<div style="display: inline-block;"> 
    <span id="LBL_Xmin" class="labelsAxis">X :</span>
    <input name="TXT_graphXmin" id="TXT_graphXmin"
        tabindex="3" type="text" style="width:75px;">
    <span id="MainContent_LBL_Xmax"
        class="labelsAxis">to</span>
    <input name="TXT_graphXmax" id="TXT_graphXmax"
        tabindex="4" type="text" style="width:75px;">
    <br>
    <span id=LBL_Ymin" class="labelsAxis">Y :</span>
    <input name="TXT_graphYmin" id="TXT_graphYmin"
        tabindex="5" type="text" style="width:75px;">
    <span id="MainContent_LBL_YMax"
        class="labelsAxis">to</span>
    <input name="TXT_graphYmax" id="TXT_graphYmax"
        tabindex="6" type="text" style="width:75px;">
    <br>
    <br>
</div>
```

I have tryied fiddling with heights, I tryied to surround the button with `<div>` tags. Nothing works.

How can I make a button align with a div?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To your input's CSS add `vertical-align:top`:

```
<input type="submit" name="ctl00$MainContent$BT_resetZoom" value="Reset coordinates" id="MainContent_BT_resetZoom" tabindex="10" style="height:50px;width:125px;vertical-align:top;">
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/kRU6r/2/)**

The default vertical alignment is baseline, which is what gives your original output.

Answer (score 1):

Try defining the float attribute.

For input `float:left`

For div `float:right`

Comment: I want to refrain from using `float` as it causes overlapping.

Answer (score 1):

You can add

```
display:block;
float:left;
```

to your MainContent_BT_resetZoom

If you do not want to use float, then use

```
vertical-align:top;
```

on your MainContent_BT_resetZoom